# Stop ImageButton tooltip from appearing on hover through a fragment

Tags: android, tooltip, android-imagebutton, onhover, stylus-pen

Currently I observe a strange behavior of showing a tooltip "through" a fragment and I have no idea how to get rid of it. Any idea or hint would be appreciated!

I have an `ImageButton` with some `contentDescription`:

```xml
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="Content description"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_image"
            />
```

This is made, to allow user to see a help text when hovering an Stylus/S-Pen or a mouse pointer over the image. This is a desired behavior:

[image: Normal behavior]

When an `AlertDialog` is displayed over the activity, no tooltip is displayed. This is also an expected behavior:

[image: No tooltip over AlertDialog]

But, when a fragment is displayed over the `ImageButton` the tooltip is always displayed. This is a non-desired behavior and the great mystery of this question. The fragment has half-transparent green background:

[image: Tooltip over the fragment]

A simple `FrameLayout` is used in the fragment layout:

```xml
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#B94EC14A"
    />
```

As is the user can click through the fragment.

If these lines are added, one can get rid of "click through" behavior, but not from "hover through":

```java
        layout1.setClickable(true);
        layout1.setFocusable(true);

        layout1.setOnTouchListener((v, event) -> true);
        layout1.setOnHoverListener((v, event) -> true);
        layout1.setOnGenericMotionListener((v, event) -> true);
```

It looks like some other kind of events is used here.

- Which kind of events are used to translate "on hover" event through the view?
- How prevent this tooltip from appearing? (similar behavior as with AlertDialog is required)

Comment: I have a similar problem, where showing a NavigationView that covers the toolbar does not prevent the tooltips of the blocked menu icons to be shown on hover.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I could not find the cause of the problem, so I ended up starting a fragment as a Dialog:

```java
MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
...
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
fragment.setCancelable(false);
fragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "dialog");
```

Or for the different use case packing the fragment to an empty activity and starting this activity:

```java
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(...);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
```

In this case (as already described in the question) the tooltips are not displayed on hover.